# Events by Management Activity API doesn't have ClientIp Property

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365-restapi

We are polling Management Activity API for events in SharePoint, and Azure AD. But we observed that the ClientIp property is not available in event data for many events in SharePoint. Also this property is missing for all events in Azure Active Directory. Could you let us know if this is a known issue? If yes when can we expect this issue to be fixed?